# SQL oracle add a value

Tags: sql, oracle

Let`s say I want to select the students with scholarship and add to that value 150 and for those with no scholarship to add 100.I tried :

select name,scholarship+150 as "New scholarship" from students where bursa is not null union select name,scholarship+100 as "New scholarship" from students where bursa is null;

but only for those who had scholarship added the new value .Can you please help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If **scholarship** might be NULL replace it with **nvl(scholarship,0)** or **coalesce(scholarship,0)**

```
select scholarship + case when bursa is not null then 150 else 100 end ...
```

or

```
select scholarship + decode (bursa,null,100,150) ...
```

or

```
select scholarship + nvl2 (bursa,150,100) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be working fine,Unless you might have suffered following reasons

1) Reason 1:

The Arithmetic operation `NULL`+Integer_constant results in `NULL` . In simple words Adding value to Null gives you  Null.

2) Reason 2:

" `Union` eliminates duplicate values ". You may try it by checking   using `Union All`

```
select name,scholarship+150 as "New scholarship" from students where bursa is not null 
union all
select name,scholarship+100 as "New scholarship" from students where bursa is null;
```